# What will be the value of TAG?

Tags: android

Is it that the value of TAG be always the name of the package in android studio as shown below?I get a problem as logging tag can be atmost 23 characters??

```
package com.example.swangmo.intentexample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG="com.example.swangmo.intentexample";
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       Log.i(TAG,"onDestroy method called");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set tag as whatever you want. This is just for logging. Putting package there is not neccessary. I personally never do. Android will trim TAG to 23 characters. If you want to make sure it looks exactly as you wanted in your console just make sure you keep it atmost 23 characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use any string in TAG not necessarily package name. But the condition is you have to keep it below 24 characters i.e. at max 23 characters, not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The TAG is just a (static final) String, set it to whatever you want that makes it easier for you to parse the runtime log.